# WPF-Databinding via DependencyProperty and Interfaces

Tags: wpf, binding, interface, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am new to WPF and tryed to write me a custom UserControl. Therefore I added a `DependencyProperty` of type BindingList named MyComboBoxSource
In the custom Control I have a ComboBox which binds its itemssource to this List.

In my MainWindow I created an `BindingList<MyInterfaceImplementation>` and bind the property MyComboBoxSource to this list.

When I do not use the interface but use the MyInterfaceImplementation in the custom 
UserControl all works fine. But using the interface I get following error:

> Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1[WpfApplication1.MyInterfaceImplementation]' and 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1[WpfApplication1.IMyInterface]'

But wasn't able to find out how to create such an converter. I tried to implement `IValueConverter` and add this converter when setting the MyComboBoxSource-property in the mainwindow - but nothing works.

So how can i solve this? Thanks you very much! Määx.

Comment: Show that you tried, seeing the code will be easier to understand what the problem is.